# Как сократить данный js (jquery) код?

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте. Пожалуйста помогите грамотно сократить данный код, сам не справляюсь:

```js
$('.but-wd').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').show();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-wf').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').show();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-vm').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').show();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-mc').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').show();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-ca').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').show();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-bt').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').show();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-hm').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').show();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-eye').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').show();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-bug').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').show();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-bat').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').show();
  $('.hidden-qa').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
$('.but-qa').click(function() {
  $('.hidden-wd').hide();
  $('.hidden-wf').hide();
  $('.hidden-vm').hide();
  $('.hidden-mc').hide();
  $('.hidden-ca').hide();
  $('.hidden-bt').hide();
  $('.hidden-hm').hide();
  $('.hidden-eye').hide();
  $('.hidden-bug').hide();
  $('.hidden-bat').hide();
  $('.hidden-qa').show();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
```

```css
.but
 button
  display: inline-block
  background-color: #fff
  color: #111
  border: none
  outline: none
  text-align: center
  padding: 13px
  line-height: 0
  font-size: em(55px)
  margin: 0
  letter-spacing: -5px
  +mt(.18s)
  &:hover, &:focus
   color: #68ffff
   text-decoration: none
.hidden
 &-wd, &-wf, &-vm, &-mc, &-ld, &-ca, &-bt, &-hm, &-eye, &-bug, &-bat, &-sad, &-qa
  display: none
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="portfolio-item">
    <div class="rem-img-wrap">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="img/iPhone/iphone4.png" alt="iPhone">
    </div>
    <h4>iPhone 4/4S</h4>
    <span class="hidden">
        <span class="portfolio-popup price-popup">
            <span class="container-fluid">
                <span class="row">
                    <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/iPhone/iphone4.png" alt="Alt">
                    </span>
                    <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                        <h2>Неисправность:</h2>
                        <span class="but">
                        <button class="but-wd"><i class="ion-waterdrop"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-wf"><i class="ion-wifi"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-vm"><i class="ion-volume-mute"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-mc"><i class="ion-ios-mic-off"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-ca"><i class="ion-ios-camera"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-bt"><i class="ion-ios-bolt"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-hm"><i class="ion-hammer"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-eye"><i class="ion-eye-disabled"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-bug">iOS</button>
                        <button class="but-bat"><i class="ion-battery-low"></i></button>
                        <button class="but-qa"><i class="ion-help"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                        <h2>Описание:</h2>
                        <span class="portfolio-popup-text">
                            <p>
                                <span class="prev">^Выберете неисправность выше^</span>
                                <span class="hidden-wd">
                                Чай
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-wf">
                                Высокогорный
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-vm">
                                Ребята
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-mc">
                                Пили
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-ca">
                                Днем
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-bt">
                                На горе
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-hm">
                                Высокой
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-eye">
                                В палатке
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-bug">
                                С шашлычком.
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-bat">
                                В кустиках следил за ними            
                                </span>
                                <span class="hidden-qa">
                                Ара!
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, зачем столько классов делать, если есть селектор и индекс? Сколько кнопок, столько и текстов.

Comment: Радио-кнопки можно сделать через радиокнопки без js на css. Это во-первых. Во-вторых. Можно дизейблить (скрывать) все кнопки, кроме выбранной в блоке, что тоже делается за две команды `$(this).parent().hide(); $(this).show()`. Если, честно, я бы помог, но вы не описали, как конкретно и что должно работать, поэтому про радиокнопки лишь догадка, возможно ошибочная.

Comment: @higimo, тс просто хотел сократить код, возможно он еще новичок и не понимает даже, что делает.

Comment: @higimo,  _$(this).parent().hide(); $(this).show()_ если скрыть родителя - все его дочерние элементы тоже будут скрыты, не зависимо от того, какой у них стиль

Comment: @Grundy мне очень не нравится, что вы в данном вопросе не предложили своего решения, но каждому написали насколько он ошибается, не остановившись на секунду и не подумав. Конечно, я ошибся и не дописал `.find()`, вот: `$(this).parent().find('button').hide()`. Ни в коем случае, не против критики, вы правильно всё подмечаете, но поймите правильно, ваш тон не заставляет сомневаться в квалификации, но заставляет думать, что вы над всеми издеваетесь. Насколько мне известно, тут так не принято.

Comment: Добавил изображение, думаю так понятнее что должно быть. Вместо тега button, сделал бы вообще просто стилизованные ссылки, если бы было возможно тег <a> вставлять в тег <a>. Спасибо за внимание, к вопросу!

Comment: @And всё возможно. Только невозможно ответить внятно на не заданный вопрос, когда из засады смотрит Grundy, чтоб покритиковать. Я вот специально из-за этого написал комментарий, а он и тут меня настиг. Надеюсь, автору поможет любое из представленных решений и он учтёт замечания Grundy, сделав свой код лучше.

Comment: @higimo, Grundy следит, чтобы ответы были хорошими, а не тяп-ляп. То же относится и к комментариям, в которых делаются советы как делать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.but').on('click', 'button', function(){
    $('.portfolio-popup-text span').hide();
    $('.hidden-' + $(this).attr('class').split('-')[1]).show();
    $('.prev').hide();
});
```

Как подсказывают в комментарии: при таком подходе может что-то сломаться, если классы добавятся в кнопки. Поэтому в них можно добавить атрибут `data` и брать уже не класс, а атрибут

Например:

```
<button class="but-bug" data-id="bug">iOS</button>
```

и в JS будет уже:

```
$(".hidden-" + $(this).data("id")).show();
```

Comment: не угадал :-) ни разу не this и не button нужно show и hide :)

Comment: @Grundy а чо?))

Comment: ну там же классы который с _.hidden_ начинаются :-) это спаны внизу страницы :) А ты сами кнопки прячешь :)

Comment: @Grundy а, увидел..надо поправить)

Comment: это ж не сработает: _$(this).split('-')_ - у тебя this не строка, а элемент кнопки

Comment: @Grundy `$(this).attr('class').split('-')[1]` ?

Comment: _attr('class').substring(4) - плохое решение, если вдруг появится второй класс на кнопках, все может сломаться_

Comment: @Grundy ну так-то всегда может что-то сломаться... если только через `data` Тогда сделать

Comment: @Grundy сойдет?

Comment: Спасибо, за данное решение!

Answer (score 2):

Все классы с похожим именем можно найти с помощью селектора:

```
button[class^=but]
```

Что означает класс начинается на `but`

Затем отделяем из класса окончание

```
let id=$(this).attr('class').substring(4);
```

`siblings()` выделяет все соседние элементы

```js
$('button[class^=but]').click(function() {
  let id=$(this).attr('class').substring(4);
  $('.hidden-'+id).show().siblings().hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
});
```

```css
.but
 button
  display: inline-block
  background-color: #fff
  color: #111
  border: none
  outline: none
  text-align: center
  padding: 13px
  line-height: 0
  font-size: em(55px)
  margin: 0
  letter-spacing: -5px
  +mt(.18s)
  &:hover, &:focus
   color: #68ffff
   text-decoration: none

.hidden-wd
 display: none
.hidden-wf
 display: none
.hidden-vm
 display: none
.hidden-mc
 display: none
.hidden-ld
 display: none
.hidden-ca
 display: none
.hidden-bt
 display: none
.hidden-hm
 display: none
.hidden-eye
 display: none
.hidden-bug
 display: none
.hidden-bat
 display: none
.hidden-sad
 display: none
.hidden-qa
 display: none
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="rem-img-wrap">
    <img class="responsive-img" src="img/iPhone/iphone4.png" alt="iPhone">
  </div>

  <h4>iPhone 4/4S</h4>

  <span class="hidden">
  <span class="portfolio-popup price-popup">
   <span class="container-fluid">
    <span class="row">
     <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/iPhone/iphone4.png" alt="Alt">
     </span>
  <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
      <h2>Неисправность:</h2>
      <span class="but">
      <button class="but-wd"><i class="ion-waterdrop"></i>1</button>
      <button class="but-wf"><i class="ion-wifi"></i>2</button>
      <button class="but-vm"><i class="ion-volume-mute"></i>3</button>
      <button class="but-mc"><i class="ion-ios-mic-off"></i>4</button>
      <button class="but-ca"><i class="ion-ios-camera"></i>5</button>
      <button class="but-bt"><i class="ion-ios-bolt"></i>6</button>
      <button class="but-hm"><i class="ion-hammer"></i>7</button>
      <button class="but-eye"><i class="ion-eye-disabled"></i>8</button>
      <button class="but-bug">iOS</button>
      <button class="but-bat"><i class="ion-battery-low"></i>9</button>
      <button class="but-qa"><i class="ion-help"></i>0</button>
       </span>
  </span>

  <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
      <h2>Описание:</h2>
      <span class="portfolio-popup-text">
      <p>
       <span class="prev">^Выберете неисправность выше^</span>
<div>
  <span class="hidden-wd">
        Чай
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-wf">
        Высокогорный
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-vm">
        Ребята
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-mc">
        Пили
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-ca">
        Днем
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-bt">
        На горе
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-hm">
        Высокой
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-eye">
        В палатке
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-bug">
        С шашлычком.
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-bat">
         В кустиках следил за ними            
       </span>
  <span class="hidden-qa">
       Ара!
       </span>
</div>
  </p>

  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: _attr('class').substring(4)_ - плохое решение, если вдруг появится второй класс на кнопках, все может сломаться

Comment: @Grundy согласен, тут лучше использовать `id` или `data`-атрибуты. Но в данном варианте это подходит

Comment: @Crantisz, ид не может повторяться, не думаю. что вообще тут что - то надо.

Comment: @and id кнопки: `some-id`, id блока: `hidden-some-id` - и все тоже самое

Comment: @Crantisz, что все тоже самое? Один и тот же ид не может повторяться, я про это и решать на идах это не стоит. Классы могут повторяться но и классы тут не нужны, есть главный и хватает, все решит селектор и индекс, тут идет кнопка<->к<->тексту следовательно зная кнопку определим и текст. Упростит в разы задачу.

Comment: @And, в данном случае _нельзя_ утверждать, что индекс спана, который надо скрыть будет совпадать с индексом кнопки, по которой нажали. Они между собой никак не связаны.

Comment: @Grundy, они обязаны быть связанны, иначе где логика? Какой смысл делать кнопки, которые открывают текст в том-же порядке - еще и по классам? Жестоко.

Comment: @And, они связаны _названием_ которое сейчас присутствует в классах кнопки и спана: _wd_, _wf_, _bug_ и т.д. Но их позиция в разметке при этом независима друг от друга

Comment: @Grundy, Ну если порядок текста может меняться, то тогда да, а с другой стороны не вижу смысла, если позиции кнопок и текста статичны и по порядку.

Comment: @And, если они статичны, об этом нужно сделать предупреждение, что, например, данный метод будет работать при таких-то условиях. Иначе, сейчас они совпадают, а потом добавится еще одна кнопка в центр, а текст в конец и все поедет